# Column formatting with JSON add dynamic hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

I want to format a column using JSON to add a Workflow Start LINK but can not change the element ID dynamically. Can someone please help?

```
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "",
    "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow",
        "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
        "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
                "http://intranet.maib.local/sites/help/Workflows/preluareElement/preluareElement.aspx?List={7a9edd38-3f18-4bef-99f6-062067196fa2}&ID=",["$ID"],
                "&ItemGuid={690E069D-F5E7-45B3-9BED-123844A03316}&TemplateID={dbe5af40-944e-4a76-afa4-df336141cbf6}&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fintranet%2Emaib%2Elocal%2Fsites%2Fhelp%2FLists%2FCerere%2520de%2520suport%2FAllItems%2Easpx",
                "@currentField"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove `[$ID]` and write a correct element id everything works as expected.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try using `"[$ID]"`. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "",
    "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow",
        "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
        "href": {
            "operator": "+",
            "operands": [
                "http://intranet.maib.local/sites/help/Workflows/preluareElement/preluareElement.aspx?List={7a9edd38-3f18-4bef-99f6-062067196fa2}&ID=","[$ID]",
                "&ItemGuid={690E069D-F5E7-45B3-9BED-123844A03316}&TemplateID={dbe5af40-944e-4a76-afa4-df336141cbf6}&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fintranet%2Emaib%2Elocal%2Fsites%2Fhelp%2FLists%2FCerere%2520de%2520suport%2FAllItems%2Easpx",
                "@currentField"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - "[$FieldName]"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#fieldname)

> The column is formatted within the context of the entire row. You can use this context to reference the values of other fields within the same row by specifying the internal name of the field surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign, like: `[$InternalName]`

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Tank you it worked like a charm